# Search by taxonomy terms special case

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I need to search by taxonomy terms. This is pretty straight forward, but my case is somewhat special. I need to see results that contain only all tags.

for instance I would like to be able to search for a recipe that contains beef, carrots, and onions only. Recipes containing just beef and carrots, or beef and onions, would be fine too, but something that has all tags and something else would be unacceptable.

Drupal and views seem to be completely incapable of handling this scenario.
Any advice?

Thanks,